# Columns are missing in the gallery's Card Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, view-formatting

I'm using the gallery view in a Microsoft 365 SharePoint list. I'd like to add a few more fields (i.e., columns defined in the SP List) to the display, but not all the fields (column names) are available for adding.

I'm selecting the Gallery option in the view dropdown, then selecting the "Format current view".

[image]

When I choose "Edit Card" in the Card Designer I only see a subset of the list's columns are available in the "Select content" list. There are more columns defined in the SP List. How can I get them to display so that I can add them to the card?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand all the types of columns should be available for selection when formatting Gallery view. Except - MultiLine Type Column.

Check if you have those desired columns listed in the current view.

**Steps:**

1. Edit the view where you are trying to modify the card

[image]

2. Select all the columns you wish to have on the card.
3. Save the view and try to format the gallery again. Hope this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Sajid Khan’s answer is right.

As a supplement, when applying JSON formatting to the view, you can only select the columns that appear in the view, and when you hide a column, JSON formatting related to this column will be invalid.